# How do I tell if a button is being held down in OpenGL/Glut? (linux)

Tags: linux, opengl, glut

This is a similar problem: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724156/keyboard-input-hesitation-when-held-down)

Which was solved by calling GetAsyncKeyState(). While all fine and dandy, I need a Linux alternative. I need to know if a button is being *held* down, not just being pressed (because of the keyboard buffer delay). 
Does anything like this exist in the OpenGL/Glut libraries, or will I have to look elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used Glut, but I know that many people will say [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is better. I have used SDL and I like it a lot. It does everything Glut does and a lot more. In SDL, you can use `SDL_PollEvent()` to get key state without the keyboard buffer delay.

Edit: I know almost nothing about Glut, but it looks like you can use [`glutKeyboardFunc`](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node49.html) to detect normal keys, and [`glutSpecialFunc`](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node54.html) for keys that do not generate ASCII characters (such as shift). I'm not sure if there is a better way, as this doesn't seem very nice.

Comment: Looks like this is what I'm going to have to do. SDL will fix other numerous problems as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can detect when a keypress event occurs, record that state, and then listen for a key release event.

Comment: Which is what I am (sort of) currently doing. The problem is, glutKeyboardFunc() doesn't pass the current state. It only passes the ASCII character of the key.

Comment: So keep track of the button you're interested in.  You'll have to roll your own button state machine.

Answer (score 0):

As said, you will have to make your own state machine, which is easy. But you also need to use this callback method I think.

http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual/glutKeyboardUpFunc.3GLUT.xml